Maximally broad PEP-508 dependency specifier
I have the following pyproject.toml:
dependencies = [
    "first-example==*",
    "second-example",
]

The first dependency gives:
configuration error: `project.dependencies[0]` must be pep508

The second dependency gives:
warning: Missing version constraint (e.g., a lower bound) for `second-example`

How can I specify "any version"? (In this context, I have an editable install of another package, and I always want it to accept that editable install as satisfying the dependency.)

I think the issue is that a valid version specifier (as documented in PEP 440) has to include at least one concrete number; * by itself isn't a version specifier, but 0.* is, so you need to choose (or invent) a minimum valid version number for your specifier to use as a lower bound.

Try dependencies = [ "first-example>=0", "second-example>=0", ]

Who says these messages?
